# Can't make SQL Server trigger work in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to convert this mssql trigger to mysql and since it has inserted and deleted logical tables, I cannot make it work.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated :)

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[UpdateBuildCacheScenarioCounts] on [dbo].[ScenarioResults] after insert, update, delete as
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare buildidcur cursor fast_forward for (select [BuildId] from inserted group by [BuildId]) UNION (select [BuildId] from deleted group by [BuildId])
open buildidcur
declare @buildid [Int]

fetch next from buildidcur into @buildid

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    --shonky attempt at preventing deadlocks
    update [Builds] set 
        CacheTotalCount = (select Count(1) from ScenarioResults with (nolock) where [BuildId] = @buildId),
        CachePassCount = (select Count(1) from ScenarioResults with (nolock) where [BuildId] = @buildId and [IsPassed] = 1)
    where [Id] = @buildid 

    -- original, incase we need to rollback the NOLOCK
    -- update [Builds] set CacheTotalCount = (select Count(1) from ScenarioResults where [BuildId] = @buildId) where [Id] = @buildid
    -- update [Builds] set CachePassCount = (select Count(1) from ScenarioResults where [BuildId] = @buildId and [Passed] = 1) where [Id] = @buildid

    fetch next from buildidcur into @buildid
end

close buildidcur
deallocate buildidcur
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

I tried this but is not working on inserting fake values for table ScenarioResults.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE buildid INT;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE buildidcur cursor FOR (select BuildId from ScenarioResults WHERE BuildId = NEW.BuildId group by BuildId ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN buildidcur;

myloop: LOOP
    FETCH buildidcur INTO buildid;
    IF done THEN LEAVE myloop;
END IF;
    UPDATE Builds SET
    CacheTotalCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ScenarioResults WHERE BuildId = buildId),
    CachePassCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ScenarioResults WHERE BuildId = buildId AND IsPassed = 1) WHERE Id = buildid;
END LOOP;

CLOSE buildidcur;
END
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite I actually did spent 2 days on it. Sorry I didn't mention it but now I have edited the question. I am not expecting to get the answer to all my questions that is why I said suggestions as well.

Comment: Don't declare variable names with the same name as column names.

Comment: @P.Salmon It is working now with your suggestion of using different variable names :) 
Thank you so much for your help!
Finally!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The trigger produces the result I would expect

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS T;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER T AFTER INSERT ON SCENARIORESULTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE Vbuildid INT;
DECLARE VPASSED INT;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE buildidcur cursor FOR 
(select BuildId  from ScenarioResults WHERE BuildId = NEW.BuildId group by BuildId);# ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN buildidcur;

myloop: LOOP
    FETCH buildidcur INTO Vbuildid;
    INSERT INTO DEBUG_TABLE(MSG,MSG2) VALUES (VBUILDID,VPASSED);
    IF done THEN 
        LEAVE myloop;
     END IF;
    UPDATE Builds 
     SET  CacheTotalCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ScenarioResults WHERE BuildId = VbuildId),
            CachePassCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ScenarioResults WHERE BuildId = VbuildId AND IsPassed = 1) WHERE Id = Vbuildid;
END LOOP;

CLOSE buildidcur;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SCENARIORESULTS,BUILDS;
CREATE TABLE BUILDS(ID INT, CACHETOTALCOUNT INT,CACHEPASSCOUNT INT);

CREATE TABLE SCENARIORESULTS (BUILDID INT, ISPASSED INT);

MariaDB [sandbox]> TRUNCATE TABLE BUILDS;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> TRUNCATE TABLE SCENARIORESULTS;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO BUILDS VALUES (1,NULL,NULL),(2,NULL,NULL);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM BUILDS;
+------+-----------------+----------------+
| ID   | CACHETOTALCOUNT | CACHEPASSCOUNT |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
|    1 |            NULL |           NULL |
|    2 |            NULL |           NULL |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO SCENARIORESULTS VALUES (1,0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM BUILDS;
+------+-----------------+----------------+
| ID   | CACHETOTALCOUNT | CACHEPASSCOUNT |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
|    1 |               1 |              0 |
|    2 |            NULL |           NULL |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO SCENARIORESULTS VALUES (1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM BUILDS;
+------+-----------------+----------------+
| ID   | CACHETOTALCOUNT | CACHEPASSCOUNT |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
|    1 |               2 |              1 |
|    2 |            NULL |           NULL |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO SCENARIORESULTS VALUES (2,0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM BUILDS;
+------+-----------------+----------------+
| ID   | CACHETOTALCOUNT | CACHEPASSCOUNT |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
|    1 |               2 |              1 |
|    2 |               1 |              0 |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO SCENARIORESULTS VALUES (2,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM BUILDS;
+------+-----------------+----------------+
| ID   | CACHETOTALCOUNT | CACHEPASSCOUNT |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
|    1 |               2 |              1 |
|    2 |               2 |              1 |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO SCENARIORESULTS VALUES (2,0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM BUILDS;
+------+-----------------+----------------+
| ID   | CACHETOTALCOUNT | CACHEPASSCOUNT |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
|    1 |               2 |              1 |
|    2 |               3 |              1 |
+------+-----------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```